# Pie Chart in Power Apps from a Choice field of a Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have a Sharepoint list which have a column with a Choice value, I want to show how many times each value is repeated in a Pie Chart on my Power App.
When I select the chart and tell it on the **Item** properties to read my Sharepoint list data, it only goes green and shows the number of items. Example screenshot:

[image]

What I want now is to show the specific column (which is a Choice column) and give each of the options a different color.
I've been investigating and found [this link](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Pie-Chart-on-a-SharePoint-Choice-Field/td-p/198960) with a formula, but I just can't figure out how it works, because for me is just errors.

Here's the formula from the link:

```
AddColumns(
  GroupBy(
       AddColumns('20190102_case6',"NewFieldName",Office_Name.Value),
       "NewFieldName",
       "GroupData"
  ),
  "CountByOffice",
  CountRows(GroupData)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify **every parameter** in the formula to correspond to your SharePoint list.

Give the colors you want the pie chart to use under **ItemColorSet** and write the colors in order. You can copy the colors from the `PieChartSample` directly.

[image]

And here is an example for the formula:

If I want to get a chart that only use `Title` and `Number` column values, I use the formula

```
AddColumns(PieChart, "Account", Number)
```

Where `PieChart` is the source, `Account` is the custom name for the new column, `Number` is the formula for getting the values for the Account column.

Then set `Title` as **Labels** and `Account` as **Series**.

Here is the outcome:

[image]

References:
[GroupBy function.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-groupby)
[AddColumns function.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping)